# Updating state when dropdown select is changed React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

This onChange event handles the selection of a `dataschema` then makes a subsequent request to get the `queryschemas` of the selected `dataschema`. `handleChange` is working correctly and renders the appropriate `querySchemas` in a dropdown list.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const dataSchema = this.state.dataSchemas.find(dataSchema => dataSchema.name === e.target.value);
    if (dataSchema) {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${dataSchema.selfUri}/queryschemas/`,
        headers: { 'Accept': "" }
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSchema.selfUri));
          console.log(dataSchema.id)
          this.setState({
            querySchemaId: response.data.data[0].id,
            querySchemaUri: response.data.data[0].selfUri,
            querySchemaName: response.data.data[0].name,
            querySchemas: response.data.data, //has list of querySchemas from request
            selectedId: dataSchema.id
          }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.querySchemaId)
            console.log(this.state.querySchemaUri)
            console.log(this.state.querySchemaName)
            console.log(this.state.selectedId)
          });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
    }
  }

  //This is the list of querySchemas returned by the above request
  {
  "data" : [ {
    //array postion [0] -- 
    "id" : "2147483601",
    "selfUri" : "/dataschemas/2147483600/queryschemas/2147483601",
    "name" : "QS-1"
  }, {
    //array position [1]
    "id" : "2147483602",
    "selfUri" : "/dataschemas/2147483600/queryschemas/2147483602",
    "name" : "QS-2"
  } ]
}


  querySchemaChange = e => {
    const querySchema = this.state.querySchemas.find(querySchema => querySchema.name === e.target.value);
    if (querySchema) {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `/dataschemas/${this.state.selectedId}/queryschemas/${this.state.querySchemaId}/queries`,  //<--- {this.state.querySchemaId} is not updating to show the current querySchema that is selected
        headers: { "Accept": "" }
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
    }
  }
```

Then the second call is using the `querySchemaId` to make a request to the specific URI,
But `querySchemaId: response.data.data[0].id,` always grabs the first array from the response, obviously. So my issue is if I choose a different `querySchema` from the drop down it is always using the response in position `[0]` to make the next call. How can I keep the name that is selected updated in state and use the id attached to it, so it fires the right request?

These are the select elements rendering the dropdowns

```
render(){
  return ( 

    <label>
      Pick a DataSchema to filter down available QuerySchemas:
  <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {dataSchemas &&
          dataSchemas.length > 0 &&
          dataSchemas.map(dataSchema => {
            return <option value={dataSchema.name}>{dataSchema.name}</option>;
          })}
      </select>
    </label>{" "}
    <br />

    <label>
      Pick a QuerySchema to view its corresponding queries status:
    <select value={this.state.querySchemaName} onChange={this.handleChange} onChange={this.querySchemaChange}>
        {querySchemas &&
          querySchemas.map(querySchema => {
            return <option value={querySchema.name}>{querySchema.name}</option>;
          })}
      </select>
    </label>{" "}
    <br />
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to save selected value in the state (for `select`) and use event data (`id`) directly (in query url), not from state (`setState` is async, it will be updated later):

```
querySchemaChange = e => {
  const querySchema = this.state.querySchemas.find(querySchema => querySchema.name === e.target.value);
  if (querySchema) {
    const {id, name} = querySchema
    this.setState({
      querySchemaId : id, 
      querySchemaName: name
    });
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `/dataschemas/${this.state.selectedId}/queryschemas/${id}/queries`,
```

`querySchemaName` is used for current `select` value.
Is saving `querySchemaId` needed now (not used in query)? Is it used elsewhere?

Comment: Wouldn't saving the selected value to state belong in the querySchema object since that is where the change is happening? Because if I change the selection of `querySchema` to anything besides the first option, it is not updating and sending a request to the first `querySchema` every time.

Comment: The selected `querySchema` name is being updated, but how can the name be used to make the correct request?

Comment: check update - I hope it works for the right parts now.

Comment: Ah this is the concept I wasn't understanding. Makes sense now, thanks for the help, cheers.